# GraphQLError: Syntax Error: Expected Name, found @

Tags: graphql, schema, aws-amplify

Hello I am new user to GraphQL and am trying to create the schema I will use.
I saw [here](https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/graphql-transformer/connection/#many-to-many-connections) that the below structure is recommended when you have a many to many relationship.

```
type UserCommunity
  @auth
  @model(queries: null)
  @key(name: "byUser", fields: ["userID", "communityID"]
  @key(name: "byCommunity", fields: ["communityID","userID"]{
  id: ID!
  userID: ID!
  communityID: ID!
  user: User! @connection(fields: ["userID"])
  community: Community! @connection(fields: ["communityID"])
  }
```

However, when I deploy using AWS Amplify I get the following error message:

```
GraphQLError: Syntax Error: Expected Name, found @
```

It is also telling me that it is failing on this line:

```
@key(name: "byCommunity", fields: ["communityID","userID"]{
```

I've tried to find any and all documentation and looked at other stack overflow questions but haven't solved the syntax problem.

Any help would be super appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing closing `)`s on some lines:

```
-@key(name: "byUser", fields: ["userID", "communityID"]
+@key(name: "byUser", fields: ["userID", "communityID"])
```

and

```
-@key(name: "byCommunity", fields: ["communityID","userID"]{
+@key(name: "byCommunity", fields: ["communityID","userID"]){
```

Comment: SO should add a facepalm emoji because I would be using it now...
thanks for pointing that out sometimes all you need is another set of eyes!

Comment: Thanks `loganfsmyth`, in my case, I used curly brackets `{ }`, instead of parenthesis `( )`

Answer (score 2):

You're actually missing closing parentheses on both of the @key lines. Update to this, and you should be good to go.

```
type UserCommunity
  @auth
  @model(queries: null)
  @key(name: "byUser", fields: ["userID", "communityID"])
  @key(name: "byCommunity", fields: ["communityID","userID"]){
  id: ID!
  userID: ID!
  communityID: ID!
  user: User! @connection(fields: ["userID"])
  community: Community! @connection(fields: ["communityID"])
}
```

Side note: I recommend getting a GraphQL highlighter for your text editor if you don't have one. The keywords will change colors when you have a syntax issue. That's just another thing you can look out for.

Comment: guess I should've refreshed the page before posting; alas

Comment: I appreciate the help regardless! Im using VSCode as my main IDE, is there a highlighter you would recommend?

Comment: Personally I use the one called "GraphQL" from the "GraphQL Foundation"

Comment: Awesome, I'll give that one a look thanks!